# NoMethodError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new when logging in as Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I'm using `ActvieAdmin` for the backend of my app.

I did following changes to let my users use their `username` to sign up to their account.

in `config/initializers/devise.rb` I changed `config.authentication_keys = [:username]`

then I added the following lines to the `user.rb` model

```
validates :email,uniqueness: true 
validates :username,uniqueness: true
```

Then I created a migration `rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string:uniq` and then `rake db:migrate`

then in the end I modified the devise views to show `:username`

I can now log in as a user with username

But I can't log in to ActiveAdmin anymore. I get this error messages

```
NoMethodError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new

Showing /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activeadmin-1.2.1/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined method `username' for #<AdminUser id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I'm not sure How I can make ActiveAdmin log_in work again.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using multiple models with Devise (`AdminUser` and `User`), if you change the `authentication_keys` in devise initializer config, it will impose the rule for both the models. As `username` attribute is clearly missing from `AdminUser`, this method won't work for you.

If you want to authenticate **admin_users with email** and **users with username**, then you need to **add `authentication_keys` along with other devise options in the respective models instead of the initializer** like so:

```
# AdminUser
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  devise :database_authenticatable,..., authentication_keys: [:email]
  ...
end

# User
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  devise :database_authenticatable,..., authentication_keys: [:username]
  ...
end
```

You may [follow this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address) if you want to allow **any of email/username** for both type of users